# List all variables being used in a script with bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to list all the variables but this code doesn't work, any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Introduce el numero de alumnos: " alumnos

x=1

until [ $alumnos -lt $x ]; do
        read -p "La nota del alumno $x es: " nota$x
let x=$x+1
done

( set -o posix ; set ) | less | echo
```

Comment: Do you really want to list *all* variables, or just the `notaX` variables?

Comment: @chepner notaX ones

Answer (score 2):

Drop the last `| echo` in the pipeline, it doesn't make any sense there, so write just this:

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | less
```

To list only the variables starting with `nota`, you can add a `grep`:

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | grep ^nota | less
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just use `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p ${!nota*}
declare -- nota1="3"
declare -- nota2="6"
declare -- nota3="8"
```